# I want my iOS app to update user's location on the server every 2 minutes, regardless of the user's motion or position. How can I do it?

Tags: ios, location, nstimer, cllocationmanager

I am able to get location updates every 2 minutes but I noticed that the battery consumption is close to 15% per hour when I am moving. When I am not moving, the battery consumption is less.
What I have tried to do is use a timer which starts location update for 5 seconds, every 120 seconds. However, it appears that when I am moving, the location update takes place more than once every 120 seconds.

Comment: Why do you need to update the position of the user if they haven't moved? Why not compare their current location to their location 2 minutes ago and if they've moved a set amount (i.e. 100m) update the server?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new method for getting the current location in iOS 9:

[CLLocationManager requestLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestLocation)